# Html/Django - loading static image from disk failure

Tags: python, html, django, image, static

I am trying to load an image into html from my disk.

sending the template 'context':

```
context = {
    'photo': "'projectweekapp/images/1.jpg'"
}
```

Referencing the image statically works correctly as so:

```
<img src="{% static 'projectweekapp/images/1.jpg' %}" alt="">
```

but when I try this:

```
<img src="{% static {{photo}} %}" alt="">
```

I receive an error. That read "Could not parse the remainder: '{{photo}}' from '{{photo}}'"

Likewise, if I change my python to look like this:

```
context = {
'photo': "{% static 'projectweekapp/images/1.jpg' %}"
```

}

And reference the context as so:

```
<img src="{{photo}}" alt="">
```

I receive another error reading "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

I'd like some help figuring this out before I waste my whole night running in circles. Thankyou!

Comment: Where is the image located? Is it inside your static directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `<img src="{% static 'projectweekapp/images/1.jpg' %}" alt="">`, most common way.
2. `<img src="{% static {{photo}} %}" alt="">  # Incorrect`
   `<img src="{% static photo %}" alt="">  # Correct`, no extra brackets required, but no quotes either, indicating `photo` is a variable.
3. `context = {
       'photo': "{% static 'projectweekapp/images/1.jpg' %}"
   }`, don't do this, it will never work.

Comment: Glad to help ❤!